# C++11 normal_distribution and MATLAB normpdf

Tags: c++11, normal-distribution

I have to develop normpdf MATLAB function in C++ environment.
But I got a problem..

normpdf(X, u, sigma) in MATLAB
is similar with normal_distribution gaussian(u, sigma);

where is X values?
It means I want the gaussian function not gaussian random.
How I sample a output value with gaussian distribution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily write normpdf yourself

```
inline double squared(double x)
{
    return x*x;
}

double normpdf(double x, double u, double s) { 
    return (1.0/(s*sqrt(2.0*M_PI)))*exp(-0.5*squared(x-u)/squared(s));
}
```

UPDATE

This one might be a bit faster, less one multiplication

```
const double ONE_OVER_SQRT_2PI = 0.39894228040143267793994605993438;

double normpdf(double x, double u, double s) { 
    return (ONE_OVER_SQRT_2PI/s)*exp(-0.5*squared((x-u)/s));
}
```

Comment: @LocoField  As far as I can see there is no such function in standard C++ library. Please check yourself, http://en.cppreference.com/w/